# .htaccess Rewrite GET-Data into GET-Data

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i want to rewrite `http://192.168.2.101/game.php?village=567919&screen=overview` into `http://192.168.2.101/index.php?dir=game&page=overview&village=567919` can anyone tell my why this is not working well and how i do it right?

my .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ index/
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?dir=main&page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^game.php?village=(.*)&screen=(.*)$ index.php?dir=game&page=$2&village=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Try changing `village=(.*)` to `village=(.*?)`

Comment: @hjpotter92 no change...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `%{QUERY_STRING}` to parse query string parameters.

Replace your code by this one in your htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^village=([^&]+)&screen=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^game\.php$ /index.php?dir=game&page=%2&village=%1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /index.php?dir=main&page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php [L]
```